# Can a Primary Key act as Foreign Key in two different tables?

Tags: oracle

Im currently making a basic minecraft item listing database design, and im wondering if i can reference id_player with a foreign key in the Reviews Table and Listing Table[image]

Comment: Yes, of course. A primary key can be *referenced* by many [children] tables, not just two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple constraints that can reference the same primary (or unique) constraint.

If you wanted to, you could have up to 4,294,967,292 foreign keys that reference the same primary key (since the maximum number of constraints in a database is 4,294,967,293 but you would need one primary key constraint).

From the [Oracle Database Reference, Appendix A.3 Logical Database Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76)

> This table describes limit types and limit values for logical database items.
>
> | Item | Type of Limit | Limit Value |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Constraints | Maximum per column | Unlimited Oracle does not define a limit on the number of constraints per column. However, constraints are subject to the limit on the maximum number of constraints in the database. See the entry for "[Constraints - Maximum per database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76__P_J5T_5PK_ZQB)" in this table. |
> | Constraints | Maximum per database | 4,294,967,293 |